# Search users from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to search for users on facebook with an app token. Here's the endpoint that I'm accessing with the graph explorer (I've tried both app and access tokens):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?q=foo
```

Here's the error that I'm receiving:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "BbsgVF64X28"
  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#search

You need to specify a `type` parameter to be able to use the search, like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?q=foo&type=user
```